# Drush rsync and drupal composer wrong destination dir

Tags: 8, drush, composer

I'm trying to sync two D8 sites. Both set up with [drupal composer](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project) which means that the directory structure is a bit different than usual. Composer puts drupal files inside `web` sub directory like this:

```
/var/www/drupal8
|-- composer.json
|-- composer.lock
|-- drush
|-- scripts
|-- vendor
`-- web
    |-- autoload.php
    |-- core
    |-- index.php
    |-- modules
    |-- profiles
    |-- robots.txt
    |-- sites
    |-- themes
    |-- update.php
    `-- web.config
```

My aliases file looks like this:

```
<?php

$aliases["local"] = array (
  'root' => '/var/www/drupal8/web/',
  'uri' => 'http://local.site',
);

$aliases["remote"] = array (
  'root' => '/var/www/drupal8/web/',
  'uri' => 'http://site.example.com',
  'remote-user' => 'dev',
  'remote-host' => 'site.example.com',
);
```

When I do `drush rsync @remote @local` I end up with all files from `@remote/web` inside `@local/web/web` like this:

```
/var/www/drupal8
|-- composer.json
|-- composer.lock
|-- drush
|-- scripts
|-- vendor
`-- web
    |-- autoload.php
    |-- core
    |-- index.php
    |-- modules
    |-- profiles
    |-- robots.txt
    |-- sites
    |-- themes
    |-- update.php
    |-- web
        |-- autoload.php
        |-- core
        |-- index.php
        |-- modules
        |-- profiles
        |-- robots.txt
        |-- sites
        |-- themes
        |-- update.php
        `-- web.config
    `-- web.config
```

I can't edit aliases to remove `web` sub dir from `root` path because then drush will not work as it will complain that it *needs a higher bootstrap level to run* (because it won't know where is drupal root folder).

How can I instruct drush to use proper destination path for synchronisation?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem took me ages to find out what was wrong.
Turned out to be the slash (/) behind the root folder that was missing.

```
self.site.yml


remote:
  host: domain.com
  user: user
  root: /home/user/public_html/
  uri: http://domain.com
```

@see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402555/why-add-a-trailing-slash-after-an-rsync-destination

Turned out to be a bug in drush
https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/3405

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this problem. What version of Drush are you using? What version of rsync, on what OS?

I created temporary aliases for two sites, and set their root directory to /tmp/a and /tmp/b, respectively. I just put a couple of test files in /tmp/a.

```
$ tree /tmp/a
/tmp/a
├── composer.json
└── web
    └── index.php

1 directory, 2 files
$ drush rsync @tmp.a @tmp.b
You will delete files in /tmp/b/web/ and replace with data from /tmp/a/web//
Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
$ tree /tmp/b
/tmp/b
└── web
    └── index.php

1 directory, 1 file
```

This behaves as expected.

I also did another test, using a remote alias as the source, and received similar results.

If you would like to see exactly what parameters Drush is using to call rsync, add the `-s` flag to the command line:

```
drush -s rsync @remote @local
```